# Where do I find "npm" with IntelliJ?

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, npm

I am trying to prepare my IntelliJ for an new Angular 6 project/module.

According to [JB Angular tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/angular.html) I installed Node.js (Version: 182.3911.9 ) first.

Now I tried to install Angular CLi via terminal and get following error:

> E:\Projekte>npm install -g @angular/cli
>
> Der Befehl "npm" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
>
> konnte nicht gefunden werden.

Translated to English it means something like: "npm" is wrong spelled or could not be found. But npm should be installed with Node.js. How do I tell IntelliJ, were he can found Node.js, which was installed by IntelliJ?

Thanks for help!

Comment: don't iunderstand what it has to do with IDEA. Can you run npm in your windows cmd console, using same command? If it works there, but doesn't work in IDEA built-in terminal, try re-starting IDEA - environment variables are only loaded on program start, so those created/updated when it's running are not available

Comment: Looks like the folder containing the `npm` command was not added to the list of folders containing commands (PATH variable). Normally the node installer should do it. Try first to restart the terminal where you are typing this command, in case it was already opened before the installation, and then check the PATH variable

Comment: Fix ur PATH variable or switch to Linux, Cheers :)